# Any way to set small timeout (milliseconds) in SQL Server (using ADO.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

The question is in the title...  Any way I set a SqlCommand to timeout in 100ms?  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) says SqlCommand / ADO supports timeouts in full seconds only.

Basically, I have a very small insert that should take <30ms.  Sometimes SQL decides to be slow and my insert is blocked and can take 1-2 seconds.  The data inserted, however, is not mission critical and I would rather it fail than wait and block.  Can I set a very small timeout using ADO.NET?  Or should I just leave the Sql Insert as a 1sec timeout and fire-and-forget using the ASYNC methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is SQL server slow or is your table locking strategy incorrect?

Comment: If you really want to do this, lock_timeout could be what you're looking for: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Setting the lock_timeout to milliseconds sound like a bad idea, anyhow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fail the insert if the lock can't be acquired within a short period of time, set a lock timeout before executing the insert.  This will cause a timeout on the server side instead of client side.

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 100;
```